# CSS completely stopped working on my Blogspot.com site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a CSS / HTML drop down navigation for my blogspot.com site. After coding it a few hours I had accidentally closed the tab to find out no matter what or where I tried the CSS on blogspot, the CSS wouldn't work again. Now, the HTML/CSS works anywhere else, just not on blogspot anymore.

These are the things I did:

```
 1. Created a entire new blog under the same account, then applied
    html/css
 2. Cleared cookies, cache and restarted browser
 3. Tried multiple browsers
 4. Used stylish extension to override
 5. Used console in firefox to edit HTML on other sites and added my
    code to see if it worked elseware
 6. Used a different computer
 7. Used mobile network instead of ISP
```

Despite doing everything pretty much to get the css/html to work blogspot, it will refuse it now no matter what. I am guessing it is obviously an issues with blogspot.com such as a glitch or bug that I may have now caused. It also shows a lot of CSS code struck out in the styles inspector when you inspect a site via right-click.

I dab in javascript / jquery sometimes and I am wondering if there is a way to force my CSS to force override.

CSS/HTML http://jsfiddle.net/rpksx66u/

My blogspot site: https://vitalintel.blogspot.com/

Im about to pull my hair out.

update: so I moved the css/html/script element to another part of the page and it works. When the element is placed in the Cross-Column's sections in layout, it refuses to use any CSS.

Comment: For me the jsfiddle shows the same behaviour I can actually see in the site. Also if you refer to jquery or js as tag is preferible if you can add the code in relation. And remember you can use the snippet editor of SO instead of jsfiddle.Also the title of the answer does not expose an answer. I suggest you could be more precise. Since code is appearently right but we can't pretend to know your intentions. Welcome Stackoverflow Zach.

Comment: Broken on site: http://prntscr.com/gjlz6v - Working in fiddle:http://prntscr.com/gjlzc5

Comment: Assuming that the code you have is what jsfiddle shows. Expose what is not working as intended and what you want to get of that. We can't act over screenshots :)

Comment: update: so I moved the css/html/script element to another part of the page and it works. When the element is placed in the Cross-Column's sections in layout, it refuses to use any CSS.

Comment: Your HTML have unclosed tags and mistakes.

Comment: Please tell me where its broken.

Comment: The first "div" is not closed. And some "li" tags also not. I was trying to edit but at the end I dont know your purpose for menu and submenu items. So I guess if you can edit and ensure it is well done and we see if It could solve your problem or we continue talking. It could be the main error, since you are not closing the div tag and could be a reason to it doesn't work it depending where you are placing the item. So, give a look.

Comment: can you reconstruct in a fiddle, on my end it shows correct where you enter the code.